# Skip some values while counting

Tags: python

I have list:

```
s = list(map(int, ['0', '0', '2', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0']))
```

I need to figure out how to take a nonzero number from the list that has more concurrence (in this example it is *'1'*). If concurrence of numbers is the same (e.g. *['0', '2', '2', '1', '1', '0', '0']*) take first nonzero number in the list (in this example it is *'2'*). If the list consists of zeros than return zero.

It seems that

```
max(set(s), key=s.count)
```

can help but it has problems with zeros. For the example above it returns 0.

Comment: Look into [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
s =  ['0', '0', '2', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0']

try:
    print(next(t[0] for t in Counter(s).most_common(2) if t[0] != '0'))
except StopIteration:
    print('0')
```

output:

```
1
```

[Counter.most_common](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) :

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the
>   most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common()
>   returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are
>   ordered in the order first encountered

Comment: Does it possible to create function from try-except?

Comment: you can create a function that has try except :)

Comment: had a problem with it. Here my question regarding it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088675/create-function-from-try-except

Comment: what problem ??

Comment: I already got it. I needed to return from the except block as well. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` registers values in order, so it does exactly what you're looking for:

```
from collections import Counter
l = list(map(int, ['0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '0', '0']))
c = Counter(l)
del c[0]
c.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

### Output:

```
1
```

If I change the list so there's more 2 first, the output will change:

```
l = list(map(int, ['0', '0', '2', '1', '2', '1', '0', '0']))
c = Counter(l)
del c[0]
c.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

### Output:

```
2
```

Comment: If I take  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'] I got an error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Sorry, missed the  `try - except`