# Create function from try-except

Tags: python

Based on the example provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083961/skip-some-values-while-counting/61084144#61084144), how can I create a function from:

```
from collections import Counter
s =  ['0', '0', '2', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0']
try:
    print(next(t[0] for t in Counter(s).most_common(2) if t[0] != '0'))
except StopIteration:
    print('0')
```

This code doesn't work:

```
def most_common_number(s):
    try:
        return next(t[0] for t in Counter(s).most_common(2) if t[0] != '0')
    except StopIteration:
        '0'
```

If it is possible to get the same results without try-except  please let me know

Answer (score 3):

You need to return from the `except` block.

```
def most_common_number(s):
    try:
        return next(t[0] for t in Counter(s).most_common(2) if t[0] != '0')
    except StopIteration:
        return '0'
```